# Как к этому скрипту добавить часы и минуты по России?

Tags: php, дата

```
$date_RU = [
    'январь',
    'февраль',
    'март',
    'апрель',
    'май',
    'июнь',
    'июль',
    'август',
    'сентябрь',
    'октября',
    'ноябрь',
    'декабрь'
];

$month = date('n')-1;
$data = $date_RU[$month].' '.date('d, Y');
```

Comment: А вот такой вариант не пробовали: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date-default-timezone-get.php

Comment: захостить скрипт на россйском серваке ;)

Comment: . date('d, Y, h:m');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow'); // Устанавливаем временную зону. Россия большая, смотря какой регион нужен.

$date_RU = [
'январь',
'февраль',
'март',
'апрель',
'май',
'июнь',
'июль',
'август',
'сентябрь',
'октября',
'ноябрь',
'декабрь'
];
$month = date('n')-1;
$data = $date_RU[$month].' '.date("d Y G:i");
print_r($data);
```